# Logging configuration on Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

Is there a way to completely shut down the logging on Tomcat 7?
Alternatively, is it possible to setup a "less-verbose" logging level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat uses a commons-logging implementation called Juli. It internally uses Java Util Logging. So to change the logging level change the logging.properties file (jre_dir/lib) and set the console logger to WARNING:

```
 java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a logging.properties file inside conf/ directory under tomcat.

You have to open that file and change the log levels to the type you want:

For ex:

[image: TOMCAT]

You can change the log level to "INFO" in your case:

```
Log level
Description

SEVERE(highest)      Captures exception and Error

WARNING              Warning messages

INFO                 Informational message, related to the server activity

CONFIG               Configuration message

FINE          Detailed activity of the server transaction (similar to debug)

FINER         More detailed logs than FINE

FINEST        More detailed logs the FINER
```